# Swift include metal shader into library [Using swift package manager]

Tags: swift, metal, swift-package-manager

I've always worked with Xcode projects but now I'm starting a project that I want in the future run on other platforms, so I'm using Swift Package Manager to generate the project, but I'm facing an issue, my library need to include a metal shader file (also a openGL shader file), but I'm clueless on how to accomplish this.

My project has 2 parts, the library that holds the graphic stuff and the executable that is my actual application, so I want to import my graphic library into my application, but the issue is that the metal shader file is not included in the Xcode project also seems that isn't compiled/included in the bundled files for the library so I can load at runtime and use it when needed.

Also if you think I'm doing something completely wrong just point me.

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure if I' understanding your issue - I've never used the Swift Package Manager. (1) Is your Swift "library" a Framework target? (2) Are these shaders "files" that you need to access? (3) Can you turn these files *into* a bundle and manually include them in the Xcode project? If your answer to all three is "Yes", I believe I can help you.

Comment: (1) The Swift library is of default type (I think can be only dynamic or static, so must be a dylib or something like that. (2) The metal file I think must be compiled directly into metallib and you don't need to reference it directly in your code, just setup the vertex function and fragment function into the metal initialization (MTLLibrary). (3) Well I'm not quite sure if the bundled files will remain if I recreate the Xcode project (when adding some new dependency I need to recreate the Xcode project (or at  least I do this)

Comment: Yeah... all told I showed my inexperience with what you're doing. I thought it was different. I have projects (and Frameworks that I `import`) that use `CIKernels` that are files of GLSL code. When it's a Framework, the app simply needs to `import`. Sounds like I'm of no help to you, sorry.

Comment: You wrote "The metal file I think must be compiled directly into metallib and you don't need to reference it directly in your code, just setup the vertex function and fragment function into the metal initialization (MTLLibrary". So which code references it? Is it the code in the executable that has to perform metal initialization?

Comment: Its a library (the game engine) and I want to distribute it via SPM, so the shader its on the game engine. I just found that the metal shader is compiled to metallib file, so I ended up to creating a bash script, check my answer for more info, but I'm still not happy with the results, but for now I can still working on the project without need to worry to much about this, later on sure I'll find a solution or someone else come with a better approach.

Comment: Worth thinking about the design pattern. Because Metal is meant to be precompiled and in big difference to GLSL where shaders are still scripts that are applied at runtime. Your render Class will also look total different from GLSL to Metal. And the future of GLSL on Apple platforms does not look so bright, so does the deployment of ready made library not depend on platforms then? You keep the renderclass and metal shader (compiled) together in your bundle and announce the use of it when defining your MTLDevice.

Answer (score 5):

**In Xcode 12** (swift-tools-version:5.3) a .metal file can be used from within a Swift Package by using the `MTLDevice.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle:)` method.

The Swift Package should have a structure similar to:

```
-Sources
    -MetalShaders
        -MetalShaders.metal
        -MetalShaders.swift
-Tests
    -MetalShadersTests
        -MetalShadersTests.swift
```

The file `MetalShaders.metal` should contain the Metal source code, and the file `MetalShaders.swift` should contain the necessary setup code. One example for initial content of `MetalShaders.swift` is the following:

```
// A metal device for access to the GPU.
public var metalDevice: MTLDevice!

// A metal library.
public var packageMetalLibrary: MTLLibrary!

// Function to perform the initial setup for Metal processing on the GPU
public func setupMetal() {
    // Create metal device for the default GPU:
    metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    
    // Create the library of metal functions
    // Note: Need to use makeDefaultLibrary(bundle:) as the "normal"
    //       call makeDefaultLibrary() returns nil.
    packageMetalLibrary = try? metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: Bundle.module)

    // List the available Metal shader functions
    print(packageMetalLibrary.functionNames)

    //
    // ... add additional setup code here ...
    // 

}
```

With this approach, the `packageMetalLibrary` variable can then be accessed from the Xcode project that has a dependency on the Swift Package by importing the target from the swift package the same way that other frameworks or packages are imported.

```
import MetalShaders
```

It may be possible to use this approach with earlier versions of Xcode as the method `MTLDevice.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle:)` is available since iOS 10 / macOS 10.12, but the `Bundle.module` extension would need to be implemented and it is not clear if this will work.

Answer (score 5):

Put your `Shaders.metal` file to `Metal` directory. Then add recources to your target in `Package.swift`

```
.target(
   name: "TargetName",
   dependencies: [
     .product(name: "AnotherModule", package: "AnotherPackage")
   ],
   resources: [
     .copy("Metal/")
   ]
)
```

Now you can access to your library:

```
let url = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "Shaders", withExtension: "metal", subdirectory: "Metal")!
let source = try String(contentsOf: url)
let library = try device.makeLibrary(source: source, options: nil)
```

Or even better (but only for a single shader file):

```
.target(
   name: "TargetName",
   dependencies: [
     .product(name: "AnotherModule", package: "AnotherPackage")
   ],
   resources: [
     .process("Metal/Shaders.metal")
   ]
)
```

Now you can access to your library:

```
let library = try device.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: Bundle.module)
```

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 1):

```
let source = """

    #include <metal_stdlib>
    using namespace metal;

    struct Vertex {...
"""
let library = try device.makeLibrary(source: source options: nil)
print(library.functionNames)
```

Metal's class allow to build shader library from String at runtime. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/libraries
Hoping it helps.

UPD
Now it is available in a native way https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/bundling-resources-with-a-swift-package

Comment: please explain your answer briefly

Comment: not here edit your answer and add the necessary description

Answer (score 0):

Seems that right now isn't possible to do this. I'll update this when find a workaround or Apple fix this issue.

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2866

**Edit:** a temporary solution that I found was create an [bash script](https://gist.github.com/norman784/354a47a006a96f1d53fa1268a2ac7ffd) that edit the workspace settings to change the build path and then compile/copy the metallib file to the executable path (didn't tried yet to see how to work distributing the library through SPM or something like that, right now only works with the code in the same folder (i.e. Sources/MyEngine <- (this folder has the metal shader), Sources/MyGame).